# MongoDB : Remove where

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

In the MongoDB Console how can I remove a field (key) where the size of the list is bigger than 3? Here is my json document example:

```
 [{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5e52d5d665a51b1952871b4b"
    },
    "domains": {
        "youtube_com_": [
            "10.0.0.6",
            "10.0.0.3",
            "10.0.0.7"
        ],
        "imrworldwide_com_": [
            "10.0.0.2",
            "10.0.0.10",
            "10.0.0.4"
        ],
        "adadvisor_net_": [
            "10.0.0.3"
        ],
        "scorecardresearch_com_": [
            "10.0.0.2"
        ],
        "adnxs_com_": [
            "10.0.0.2",
            "10.0.0.3",
            "10.0.0.7",
            "10.0.0.6",
            "10.0.0.9"
        ],
        "doubleclick_net_": [
            "10.0.0.8",
            "10.0.0.7"
        ],........
```

Inside the field (key) `domains`, for each domain's name, check if the number of IP addresses is less than 3. If so, delete the domain.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a complicated aggregate query, but this is where I prefer pymongo as it's (IMHO) a lot clearer:

```
records = db.mycollection.find()
for record in records:
    domains = record.get('domains')
    for domain in domains.copy():
        ips = domains.get(domain)
        if len(ips) <3:
            record['domains'].pop(domain)

    db.mycollection.replace_one({'_id': record['_id']}, record, upsert=True)

pprint.pprint(db.mycollection.find_one({}))
```

This deletes any domains with less than 3 entries (adjust the `if len(ips) <3` logic as needed):

```
{'_id': ObjectId('5e530f9277fa4a34f9c5c2be'),
 'domains': {'adnxs_com_': ['10.0.0.2',
                            '10.0.0.3',
                            '10.0.0.7',
                            '10.0.0.6',
                            '10.0.0.9'],
             'imrworldwide_com_': ['10.0.0.2', '10.0.0.10', '10.0.0.4'],
             'youtube_com_': ['10.0.0.6', '10.0.0.3', '10.0.0.7']}}
```

Comment: This is right but I don't want to use a double loop, I want to do it with a simple query if it possible .

Comment: Ok well you didn't say that. Why is that so important?